# Show by Resolution that a set of clauses is unsatisfiable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, unification

Im trying to show by resolution that the following set of clauses is unsatisfiable:

> $\{ p(x,f(y)) \lor p(c,z), ¬p(y,f(f(y))) \lor ¬p(c,x) \}$.

Now, I know that to show the unsatisfiability I need to derive an empty clause from the original clause set. So far Ive only done exercises with at least one clause having just one literal. This time I dont understand how I can end up with empty clause when theres always two literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

In order to apply [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_first_order_logic) to predicate logic, you have to use [Unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_general_unifier).

Step 1) : use the substitution $z \leftarrow x$ with $¬p(c,x)$ to get $¬p(c,z)$ and resolve with: $p(x,f(y)) \lor p(c,z)$ to get

> $p(x,f(y))$.

Now you have to clauses : $p(x,f(y))$ and $¬p(y,f(f(y)))$.

Find a suitable substitution to unify them and you wll get the [empty clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)#Empty_clauses) : $\square$.